# ¿como solucionar un "memory leak" en react sin usar hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Este es el codigo que tengo y aun no se usar apropiadamente los ciclos de vida, pero el error en la consola me sugiere que use "ComponentWillUnmount" para arreglar este "memory leak", pero no se como hacerlo, lo que intente hasta ahora no funciono, este es el codigo que genera el deterioro de performance, (no hagan caso a la parte de redux).
Este es el repo, el branch es "frontend" https://github.com/Ceci007/final-capstone-frontend

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import FormIllness from '../../components/FormIllness/FormIllness';
import {
  fetchUserIllness, createIll, deleteIll,
} from '../../actions/illness';
import { loginStatus } from '../../actions/user';
import './Illness.css';

class Illness extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      addForm: false,
      editForm: false,
      idIll: '0',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { user, fetchUserIllness } = this.props;
    const ID = user.user.id;
    fetchUserIllness(ID);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { illness } = this.props;
    const {
      addForm, editForm,
    } = this.state;
    return illness !== nextProps.illness
    || addForm !== nextState.addForm
    || editForm !== nextState.editForm;
  }

  addIllness = (name, description) => {
    const { createIll, user } = this.props;
    const { addForm } = this.state;
    const userId = user.user.id;
    createIll({ name, description, userId });
    this.setState({
      addForm: !addForm,
    });
  };

  displayForm = () => {
    const { addForm } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      addForm: !addForm,
    });
  }

  displayEdit= e => {
    const { editForm } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      editForm: !editForm,
      idIll: e.target.id,
    });
  }

  deleteIll = id => {
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { deleteIll } = this.props;
    const userId = user.user.id;
    deleteIll({ userId, id });
  }

   changeEditForm = () => {
     const { editForm } = this.state;
     this.setState({
       editForm: !editForm,
     });
   }

   changeAddForm = () => {
     const { addForm } = this.state;
     this.setState({
       addForm: !addForm,
     });
   }

   render() {
     const { illness } = this.props;
     const {
       addForm, editForm, idIll,
     } = this.state;
     return (
       <main className="main">
         <button type="button" className="add-ill" onClick={this.displayForm}>+</button>
         <div className="illnesses">
           { !editForm && !addForm && <h3>Your Illnesses</h3>}

           {illness.length === 0 && !addForm && <div className="tracking">Start adding a illness you want to track here!</div>}
           {illness.map(ill => (
             <div key={ill.id}>
               { !editForm && !addForm && (
               <div className="one-ill">
                 <div className="buttons">
                   <button type="button" onClick={() => this.deleteIll(ill.id)}>
                     <i className="fa fa-trash-o" />
                   </button>
                   <button type="button" onClick={this.displayEdit}>
                     <i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o" id={ill.id} />
                   </button>
                 </div>
                 <div className="ill-info">
                   <Link to={{
                     pathname: `illness/${ill.id}`,
                     state: {
                       nameill: ill.name,
                     },
                   }}
                   >
                     {!editForm && (
                     <div>
                       <div className="ill-name">
                         <p>Name:</p>
                         <p>Description:</p>
                       </div>
                       <div className="ill-description">
                         <p>{ill.name}</p>
                         <p>{ill.description}</p>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     )}
                   </Link>
                 </div>
               </div>
               )}
               { editForm && ill.id.toString() === idIll && <FormIllness actionToPerform="Save Changes" buttonId={idIll} changeEditForm={this.changeEditForm} />}
             </div>
           ))}
         </div>
         <div className="newill">
           {addForm && <FormIllness addIllness={this.addIllness} actionToPerform="Add" changeAddForm={this.changeAddForm} />}
         </div>
       </main>
     );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    user: state.user,
    isLogin: state.user.isLogin,
    illness: state.illness,
  });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchUserIllness: data => dispatch(fetchUserIllness(data)),
  createIll: data => dispatch(createIll(data)),
  deleteIll: id => dispatch(deleteIll(id)),
  loginStatus: () => dispatch(loginStatus()),
});

Illness.propTypes = {
  fetchUserIllness: PropTypes.func,
  createIll: PropTypes.func,
  deleteIll: PropTypes.func,
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    user: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
    }),
  }),
  illness: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    description: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string,
  })),
};

Illness.defaultProps = {
  createIll: () => {},
  deleteIll: () => {},
  fetchUserIllness: () => {},
  illness: {},
  user: {},
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Illness);
```

Este es el formulario

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './FormIllness.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateIll } from '../../actions/illness';

class FormIllness extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { actionToPerform, buttonId, illness } = this.props;
    if (actionToPerform === 'Save Changes') {
      const ill = illness.filter(x => x.id.toString() === buttonId);
      this.setState({
        name: ill[0].name,
        description: ill[0].description,
      });
    }
  }

  handleChangeName = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleChangeDescription = e => {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (name, description) => {
    const { addIllness } = this.props;
    addIllness(name, description);
  }

  handleUpdate = async id => {
    const { name, description } = this.state;

    const {
      user, updateIll, changeEditForm,
    } = this.props;

    const data = {
      id,
      user_id: user.user.id,
      name,
      description,
    };

    await updateIll(data);
    changeEditForm();
  }

  render() {
    const { name, description } = this.state;
    const {
      actionToPerform, illness, buttonId, changeEditForm, changeAddForm,
    } = this.props;
    const ill = illness.filter(x => x.id.toString() === buttonId);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          {actionToPerform}
          {' '}
          Illness
        </h3>
        <form
          className="one-form"
          onSubmit={
           actionToPerform === 'Add'
             ? () => this.handleSubmit(name, description) : () => this.handleUpdate(ill[0].id)
}
        >
          <div className="one-parameter">
            <label htmlFor="name">
              Name:
              <input
                required
                id="name"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                defaultValue={buttonId === '0' ? name : ill[0].name}
                onChange={this.handleChangeName}
              />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="one-parameter">
            <label htmlFor="description">
              Description:
              <textarea
                id="description"
                name="description"
                defaultValue={buttonId === '0' ? description : ill[0].description}
                onChange={this.handleChangeDescription}
              />
            </label>

          </div>
          <div className="buttons-form">
            {actionToPerform === 'Add' && <button type="submit">{actionToPerform}</button>}
            {actionToPerform === 'Save Changes' && <button type="submit">Save</button>}
            {actionToPerform === 'Add' && <button type="button" onClick={changeAddForm}>Cancel</button>}
            {actionToPerform === 'Save Changes' && <button type="button" onClick={changeEditForm}>Cancel</button>}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

FormIllness.propTypes = {
  addIllness: PropTypes.func,
  actionToPerform: PropTypes.string,
  changeAddForm: PropTypes.func,
  illness: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
  buttonId: PropTypes.string,
  updateIll: PropTypes.func,
  changeEditForm: PropTypes.func,
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    user: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
    }),
  }),

};

FormIllness.defaultProps = {
  changeAddForm: () => {},
  addIllness: () => {},
  actionToPerform: '',
  illness: [],
  buttonId: '0',
  updateIll: () => {},
  changeEditForm: () => {},
  user: {},
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
  illness: state.illness,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateIll: data => dispatch(updateIll(data)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormIllness);
```

Comment: ¿Podés agregar el repositorio en cuestión en una edición?

Comment: Podrías poner el mensaje de warning exacto por favor, para ver si indica algo referente a que función está causando el memory leak? tengo la sospecha de que sería esta: ```handleUpdate = async id => {``` estás usando una función asíncrona pero no veo que la finalices con un ```return```

Comment: deberia ser ```return await updateIll(data);``` ? ok gracias

Comment: creo que podrías poner simplemente ```return;``` al final si no necesitas retornar nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In branch: front-end

In file: src/containers/Login/index.js

In line 55 of the handleErrors function:

If you comment that line you wouldn't be making a call from an unmounted component.

After the three-second delay of that function, the Login component is already unmounted. That's the cause of the error.

Happy coding!

```
  handleErrors = () => {
const { errors } = this.state;
// setTimeout(() => this.setState({ errors: '' }), 3000);
if (errors.length > 0) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {errors.map(error => <li key={error}>{error}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: Yep in Login and Signup I removed that, You are right

Comment: Hay que traducir la respuesta, esto es Stack Overflow en español.